# Submit button working in Chrome but not Firefox or IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a submit button which seems to be clickable in Chrome but not in FF or IE.  Any help would be appreciated!  I feel like the formatting of the button is incorrect.

```
  <button> <img src="http://button_image.png" onclick="mySubmit();" ></button>
```

The JQ attached to the mySubmit is:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
function mySubmit(){
    var myForms = $("form");
    myForms.each(function(index) {
        var form = myForms.eq(index);
        var serializedForm = form.serialize();
        serializedForm += '&s_referer_fname='+$('#s_refererFname').val();
        $.post("http://post.aspx", serializedForm, function (data, status) {
            if (status === "success"){
                window.location.href= "http:url.aspx?";
            }  
        });   
    });
}
</script>
```

Comment: Do you have any errors in your developer console?

Comment: can we see the rest of the html for the form

Comment: Does the `<button>` element is inside a `<form>` element? If you - you need to `preventDefault` inside the `mySubmit` to make sure the form is not submmitted by the html (the button default action).

Comment: My guess is that clicking the button in FF or IE actually clicks the button and not the image, hence no event is triggered for the image.

Comment: add the click event to the button not the image (it will bubble up)

Comment: Do you have any errors in your developer console?

Answer (score 4):

In FF and IE it seems the `onclick` event is captured by the button and not the image tag.

If you want to trigger the event cross-browser assign it to the button.
That way it gets propagated up from the image in browsers that raise it from the image while other browsers capture it on the button right away.

```
<button onclick="mySubmit();"> <img src="http://button_image.png" ></button>
```

Will work in FF, IE and Chrome ► https://jsfiddle.net/aspqwc3p/1/

Comment: This answer explains the scenario the OP is experiencing

Comment: Yes it does.  Thank you Wahl! I really appreciate the speedy response.  Tested and CONFIRMED!

Answer (score 1):

If you want an image to be a submit button you you should use the `input` tag with the `type="image"` attribute:

```
 <input type="image" src="http://button_image.png" onclick="mySubmit();" />
```

Note that inside your `mySubmit` function you should disable the default behavior using `preventDefault()`:

```
function mySubmit() {
    this.preventDefault();
```

Answer (score 0):

It's generally recommended not to put any JavaScript in your HTML. Try giving your button an ID and using

```
$('#yourid').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  .... your code
});
```

in your javascript. (and put your script tag at the very end of your html)